# Java: int << (-1) == 0 ？

Tags: java

In java, when I move a int, no matter what value it is, to the left:

```
4 << (-1);
```

when the offset is -1, I will always get 0.

Why?

Comment: Only the lower 5 bits of the shift are used so you are shifting by 31.  This means that 1 << -1 should be Integer.MIN_VALUE not 0.  For a `long` the lower 6 bits are used. See http://ideone.com/C2m9gi for an example of where it is not 0.

Answer (score 1):

Only the lower 5 bits of the shift are used so you are shifting by 31. This means that 1 << -1 should be Integer.MIN_VALUE not 0. For a long the lower 6 bits are used.

See http://ideone.com/C2m9gi for an example of where it is not 0.

```
System.out.println(1 << -1);
```

In short, you always get 0 because you keep trying even numbers. Try an odd number and you get Integer.MIN_VALUE.